# How to create an Android virtual device of a deprecated version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm using Android Studio with the following version information:

```
Android Studio 3.1.4
Build #AI-173.4907809, built on July 23, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.13.3
```

The API level 10 (Android 2.3.3) is marked as deprecated, and I'm unable to create a virtual device with this version. Is there any way to make it possible to create and boot an AVD marked as deprecated in the Android Studio?

[image]

EDIT (and possible solution): the download button was hidden by default window and table width:
[image]

Comment: use genymotion.

Comment: To create you need the system image to download and if its not available so you wont be able to do it and run in emulator. Use SDK manager to download SDK for that particular OS and then create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check sdk manager and make sure you have downloaded atleast one system image that you intend to use. Once you have downloaded it you will be able to use it from avd manager.

Sdk Manager
[image]

Avd Manager
[image]

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, but one note for anyone else reaching this issue: for some reason I also had to install the recommended updates in SDK Manager so that the installed API would be available in AVD Manager

EDIT: I spoke too soon, it still appears marked as deprecated and the "Next" button greyed out

Comment: It might be due to latest image downloaded being compatible with latest released build tools

Comment: try to restart your android studio.

Comment: also make sure you are selecting image that you have downloaded.

Comment: It was a problem between the chair and the keyboard: I was able to download the system images on SDK Manager, but in the AVD Manager the "Download" link button was hidden by the default table width.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. If it did, then there's a small "bug/question" in Android Studio -> Why mark an image to "Download" on AVD Manager, if the user has downloaded it via SDK Manager. Are the "system images" downloaded by both the same files? Or one is "source files" (via SDK) and the other "image for emulating" (via AVD)?